# Dynamically build rack app using authentication with DAV4Rack

Tags: ruby, rack, webdav

I'm trying to build a webdav implementation using rack and dav4rack, that will automatically bring a user to their own directory based on login. So, a (not working) example with config.ru:

```
map '/webdav' do

  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    Site.valid_login? username, password
    @site = Site[username: username]
  end

  run DAV4Rack::Handler.new(
    root: @site.files_path,
    root_uri_path: '/webdav'
  )

end
```

However, I can't get @site.files_path to work, because it creates the app on startup, and here I need to dynamically create the DAV4Rack::Handler for each incoming request.

Is it possible to do this with Rack?

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
map '/webdav' do

  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    Site.valid_login? username, password
  end

  run lambda { |env|
    handler = DAV4Rack::Handler.new(
      root: Site[username: env['REMOTE_USER']].files_path,
      root_uri_path: '/webdav'
    )
    handler.call(env)
  }

end
```